# HP notebook 17 - partial memory detection problem - U20.04

Tags: kernel, 20.04, ram

Do you have any suggestion to help me recover my full physical memory? I already searched in the bios and added the mem=8000mb command line to my grub.

```
dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.1 present.
SMBIOS implementations newer than version 3.2.0 are not
fully supported by this version of dmidecode.

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
 Location: System Board Or Motherboard
 Use: System Memory
 Error Correction Type: None
 Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
 Error Information Handle: 0x0008
 Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
 Array Handle: 0x0009
 Error Information Handle: 0x000F
 Total Width: Unknown
 Data Width: Unknown
 Size: No Module Installed
 Form Factor: SODIMM
 Set: None
 Locator: Bottom - Slot 1 (left)
 Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
 Type: Unknown
 Type Detail: Unknown
 Speed: Unknown
 Manufacturer: Unknown
 Serial Number: Unknown
 Asset Tag: Not Specified
 Part Number: Unknown
 Rank: Unknown
 Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
 Minimum Voltage: Unknown
 Maximum Voltage: Unknown
 Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
 Array Handle: 0x0009
 Error Information Handle: 0x0011
 Total Width: 64 bits
 Data Width: 64 bits
 Size: 8192 MB
 Form Factor: SODIMM
 Set: None
 Locator: Bottom - Slot 2 (right)
 Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
 Type: DDR4
 Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
 Speed: 2400 MT/s
 Manufacturer: A-DATA Technology
 Serial Number: 03FE0100
 Asset Tag: Not Specified
 Part Number: AO1P26KC8T1-BXPS    
 Rank: 1
 Configured Memory Speed: 2400 MT/s
 Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
 Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
 Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
```

```
free -m
              total       utilisé      libre     partagé tamp/cache   disponible
Mem:           5430        1090        2904           8        1435        4071
Partition d'échange:        7628           0        7628
```

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        5561136 kB
MemFree:         2973908 kB
MemAvailable:    4168464 kB
Buffers:           85192 kB
Cached:          1285988 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1296168 kB
Inactive:         865032 kB
Active(anon):     791476 kB
Inactive(anon):     7132 kB
Active(file):     504692 kB
Inactive(file):   857900 kB
Unevictable:          16 kB
Mlocked:              16 kB
SwapTotal:       7812092 kB
SwapFree:        7812092 kB
Dirty:               256 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        790120 kB
Mapped:           377264 kB
Shmem:              8576 kB
KReclaimable:      98504 kB
Slab:             282468 kB
SReclaimable:      98504 kB
SUnreclaim:       183964 kB
KernelStack:       10320 kB
PageTables:        14336 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    10592660 kB
Committed_AS:    4631600 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       31540 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:            17408 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      347460 kB
DirectMap2M:     5345280 kB
DirectMap1G:     2097152 kB
```

```
dmesg | grep -i memory
[    0.004619] check: Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.005246] Early memory node ranges
[    0.024230] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.024232] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.024233] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x09ed0000-0x09ffffff]
[    0.024234] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0a200000-0x0a20afff]
[    0.024235] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x39cec000-0x39cecfff]
[    0.024237] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x39cf9000-0x39cf9fff]
[    0.024237] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x39cfa000-0x39cfafff]
[    0.024238] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x39d08000-0x39d08fff]
[    0.024239] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x57321000-0x57321fff]
[    0.024241] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x577f5000-0x57802fff]
[    0.024242] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x5a3f5000-0x5a51cfff]
[    0.024242] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x5a51d000-0x5a55bfff]
[    0.024243] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x5a55c000-0x5aaf1fff]
[    0.024243] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x5aaf2000-0x5db68fff]
[    0.024244] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x5f000000-0xdfffffff]
[    0.024245] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xe0000000-0xf7ffffff]
[    0.024245] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
[    0.024245] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfcffffff]
[    0.024246] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfd000000-0xfdffffff]
[    0.024246] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe000000-0xfe6fffff]
[    0.024247] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe700000-0xfe700fff]
[    0.024247] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe701000-0xfeb7ffff]
[    0.024247] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfeb80000-0xfec01fff]
[    0.024248] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec02000-0xfec0ffff]
[    0.024248] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec10000-0xfec10fff]
[    0.024248] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec11000-0xfecfffff]
[    0.024249] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed00fff]
[    0.024249] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed01000-0xfed3ffff]
[    0.024249] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed44fff]
[    0.024250] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed45000-0xfed7ffff]
[    0.024250] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed80000-0xfed8ffff]
[    0.024250] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed90000-0xfedc1fff]
[    0.024251] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfedc2000-0xfedcffff]
[    0.024251] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfedd0000-0xfedd3fff]
[    0.024251] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfedd4000-0xfedd5fff]
[    0.024252] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfedd6000-0xfedfffff]
[    0.024252] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfeefffff]
[    0.024252] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfef00000-0xfeffffff]
[    0.024253] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff]
[    0.048834] Memory: 5412228K/5692352K available (14339K kernel code, 2397K rwdata, 4952K rodata, 2712K init, 4992K bss, 280124K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.259516] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K
[    0.389753] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
[    0.559576] Freeing initrd memory: 48372K
[    0.564344] check: Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    1.108019] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2040K
[    1.108750] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2712K
[    1.109521] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 2008K
[    1.109930] Freeing unused kernel image memory: 1192K
[    2.963206] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 2780568 KiB
[    2.963209] [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 KiB
[    2.963567] [drm] amdgpu: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    2.963578] [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
```

Many thanks by advance.

Comment: Why the `mem=8000mb`?

Comment: I found this advice on other topics > pass the instruction from a 8GB memory in grub. So I tried it...

Comment: It limits your memory. Remove it. Then `sudo update-grub` and reboot. Then show me `free -h`. If it still doesn't show 8G, move the SODIMM to the other slot and retest with `free -h`.

Comment: If it still doesn't show 8G, then go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: Bios claims 8gb, memtest86 says 6106M and free -h, after grub modifying, 5,8 Gi ... nobody agrees :-) I didn't dare to disassemble the laptop because I received it four days ago. I think a quick contact with the support will be necessary!

Comment: To be complete the 4 mem tests passed without error.

Comment: Do you have Windows installed? If so, what does it report? Also, you can try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see what it reports. That will eliminate problems with the installed Ubuntu. And yes, you may have to contact Support, as you may have a hardware problem.

Comment: I've tested it with a Fedora live stick and free -h command gives 5,8 Gi available too. All that remained was to reinstall windows 10 with the following result: 8192 Mo (amount of physical memory installed on the computer) & 6058 Mo (amount of physical memory available for the system). I've tested the memory with Win wich hasn't detect problem. I've updated the bios through win10 and installed sofware to be supported by HP. I think I'll report now to HP support. I will give you the final result... Many thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: After weeks of struggling, I can finally send this laptop back... It was like... Linux had broken the machine :-) Thanks again for the help

Comment: Sorry to hear that it didn't get resolved. Thanks for the update.